# Creating Haskell instance declarations

Tags: haskell, instance, declaration, show

complete noob to Haskell here with probably an even noobier question. I'm trying to get ghci output working and am stuck on instance declarations. How could I declare an instance for "(Show (Stack -> Stack))" given:

```
data Cmd = LD Int
         | ADD
         | MULT
         | DUP
         deriving Show

type Prog = [Cmd]

type Stack = [Int]

type D = Stack -> Stack
```

I've been trying to create a declaration like:

```
instance Show D where show = Stack
```

but all my attempts have resulted in illegal instance declarations. Any help and/or references much appreciated!

Comment: It is not clear from your code what you would want e.g. `show (\s -> 1:s)` to return.

Comment: I have a hunch you are trying to define an instance of Show for D not because it is really what you want (it's hard to imagine what it could do) but because the compiler is telling you that you need one because you have a type error somewhere; is that possible?  If so, the solution is to fix your other code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, by default, type synonyms (that is, stuff defined using `type`) aren't legal in instance declarations. There's a GHC extensions to allow this, however.

Beyond that, in this specific case, `show` needs to return a `String`; your instance is trying to return a... type synonym name, which doesn't even make sense to begin with, and besides refers to a list of `Int`, which is the wrong return type for `show`.

Finally, `D` is a function type--what is that supposed to `show`, anyway? There's really not much you can meaningfully do with a `Show` instance on a function type, in most cases.

If you just want it to say "this is type D", you could write an instance like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
instance Show D where show _ = "Stack -> Stack"
```

I'm not sure how useful that is in practice, though.

Comment: Maybe he wants to show the mutation from one [ Int ] to another [ Int ]?

Not certain how you would go intercepting this, displaying the parameter then the resultant.